# How to intergrate PDF viewer(display) in the GTK+ interface

Tags: unix, user-interface, gtk, pdfviewer

Am working on the project in which am required to fetch files from the server and to display them on the client post.All of this is to be done in the UNIX environment where I used C language for coding client and server and GTK+ for the interface which will display files in the PDF format.

My problem is I do not know how can I intergrate a PDF viewer in such interface.
As the final results I would like when I select the file and click GTKbutton it displays the file in a PDF format in that intergrated viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [EvView](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libevview/stable/) and [EvDocument](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libevdocument/stable/index.html) libraries. They are not too well documented but it's a GTK widget for displaying PDFs and other documents.

Comment: That's 404 now.

Comment: They moved to developer-old.gnome.org, I updated the links