# Display pdf document in flutter windows

Tags: linux, windows, macos, flutter, desktop-application

I have been finding it difficult to display a pdf on flutter windows  and other desktop applications. Can someone help me out

Comment: what is flutter window?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575601/flutter-pdf-viewer-for-linux-desktop?r=SearchResults), but for Windows, so the answer is the same at a high level. As with Linux, `PlatformView` is not yet supported for Windows.

Two options that could work without `PlatformView` support:

- Swap the window between displaying the Flutter view and a PDF view (if you want the PDF to fill the window while displayed).
- Place the Flutter view and the PDF view side by side in the window (if you want both Flutter content and PDF content visible at the same time).

Both would require the work to be done in the native code, so you would need to either write a plugin, or implement it directly in your runner, and use a method channel to coordinate between Dart and native code.